# Javascript Garbage Collection pauses

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I am trying to create a simple game engine in JavaScript with WebGl, but I am having some undesired problems with JavaScript in general, which I hope can be avoided. Besides the overall lack of performance with JavaScript, I am having some strange pauses when rendering with WebGl, which happen periodically, once every second or so. I assume this has to happen with GC in JavaScript. Is there anyway to minimize these "stutters"? Are there any common practices I should know, a way to force, at least part of the garbage collection, to happen at a time that I can control?

I know these are simple questions, but I am fairly new to JavaScript, and searching on the internet did not give me to many useful information.

Comment: Of course it *may* be GC, but in my experience, always when we blamed GC for something, it turned out we had an ordinary mistake somewhere in the code.

Comment: Use your browser's profiling tools! As @Boldewyn suggested, the problem might not actually be GC. Optimizing prematurely can often lead to needlessly complex code, but optimizing without any profiling metrics will probably lead to complex code *and* not even actually improve performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-use objects as often as possible. If you are creating dozens of objects (like vectors and matrices) for each rendered frame then you will definitely receive GC-related stuttering.
So when you are using a scene-graph based approach for rendering your game you might want to cache objects in the scene graph nodes for example. Or you can use the [Object Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). In other languages like Java this technique is deprecated because the object creation and GC is so fast today that a object pool doesn't help anymore. But in JavaScript it might still help.

I had GC-stutter-problems in a JavaScript game I wrote last year and I solved it by rewriting my 2D vector engine so absolutely no new objects are created during frame rendering. Objects are only created once when the scene is build-up or new scene nodes are added to it. But displaying and animating the scene creates absolutely no new objects.

You may want to take a look at my 2D engine:

http://www.ailis.de/~k/hg/javascript/twodee/file/tip/src/main/javascript/twodee

You'll notice that I cache temporarily needed vectors and matrices in static fields and that I used mutable vector and matrix classes instead of immutable so existing vectors/matrices are modified instead of creating new result vectors/matrices when doing math with them.